What does "Common frequency offset" plot means in gnss raw measurements?
I'm using Google's MATLAB code to analyze raw gnss measurement made with gnsslogger android app. In plots, there is one in particular that I don't understand the meaning, which is "Common frequency offset" plot. At first I thought it was how much the "Common bias clock offset" was varying, but as you can see, when this latter gets a spike, the "Common frequency offset" doesn't change much. So what is the meaning? I searched everywhere but haven't found anyhting. Has Doppler effect something to do with it?

$$ \mathbf{x} \text{ axis is time (seconds)}$$

@uhoh they are seconds

UPDATE: I'm giving up, I can't find much in web. But this is what I think this plot is:
I THINK it's how quickly per second the rx clock drifts, but: if for example I put a big delay in spoofing in Matlab code, then I have an incredible peak in "common bias block" plot, BUT the "common freq offset" DOESN'T change a thing, you don't notice anything. so MAYBE this plot is performed post bias estimation so after position calculation https://developer.android.com/develop/sensors-and-location/sensors/gnss#interactive-plots maybe we can say it's "aseptic" to the delays and therefore it actually tells me the real user clock drift

Hi @allexj I suggest leave the question open and remove your "I'm giving up answer". It's obvious from the Up votes others' think it's a good question. (I don't understand the question so I can't help.)
Some questions stay around for a long time until someone realises they know the answer.
